# Working with Datalist in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

good morning to all.

i place a datalist in my project in that i place a link button when i click on that link button a panel will open in that row with a textbox and a button. it is working fine but my problem is if i click on one  link button of a row panel will open, when i click on second row link button the sencond row panel is opening but first row panel is not closing. I think you get my point owhter wise i will explain again  this is my code check out

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:DataList ID="Mydatalist" runat ="Server"
              OnItemCommand="Mydatalist_ItemCommand" >
  <ItemTemplate >
    <table >
      <tr>
        <td>
          <asp:Label ID="lblcouname" runat ="server"
                     Text ='<%# Eval("country_name") %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td> 
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkrepl" Text="reply"
                          CommandName ="reply" runat ="server"
                          CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("country_id") %>'>
          </asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
       <asp:Panel ID="mypane" runat ="Server" Visible ="false"  >
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtpane" runat ="Server" ></asp:TextBox><br />
         <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="Server" Text ="Insert" />
       </asp:Panel>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</div>
</form>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Datlist : System.Web.UI.Page
{
SqlConnection con; SqlDataAdapter da; DataSet ds;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(
         @"server=msmsm;database=pop;user id=sa;password=abc");
    con.Open();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        getCountry();
    }
}
public void getCountry()
{
    string sqr="select * from country";
    da=new SqlDataAdapter (sqr,con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds,"country");
    Mydatalist.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    Mydatalist.DataBind();
}
protected void Mydatalist_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Panel pn = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("mypane");
    pn.Visible = false;
    if (e.CommandName == "reply")
    {

        pn.Visible = true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to programmably hide it.  THe DataList should have an items property, and as such you can loop through all items, find the panel control using FIndControl, and set its visibility to false.

EDIT: So you need to do:

```
private void HideItems()
{
    foreach (var item in this.dl.Items)
    {
       var panel = item.FindControl("mypane") as Panel;
       if (panel != null)
           panel.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

In ItemCommand, call this method to hide all the existing control's panels.

Comment: Mr.Brian i edit my question and i place the code please check out

Comment: OK, ItemCommand will only fire for the panel you want to set to true; you need to add in the following code in my post above.